# Delete duplicate entries mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name as bursary,

there is duplicate entries in the username, how can I delete the duplicate entries.?

here is my bursary table,

```
UserID    UserName
  1       ca11074
  2       ca11074
  3       cb56456
  4       cb56456
```

I need to delete duplicate entries.

here I tried but unfortunately not working.

```
$sql = 
"DELETE FROM bursary  
WHERE UserName IN (SELECT UserName FROM bursary (COUNT(*) > 1)";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Which one do you want to keep? Also, as attempts go, this is fairly pathetic :-(

Comment: What does 'is not working' mean? What error messages do you get *after applying [appropriate error checking techniques](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-errno.php)*?

Comment: I just want to keep the Username without any duplicates. Delete if the UserName exists same

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$sql = "ALTER IGNORE TABLE `bursary` ADD UNIQUE INDEX index_name (`UserName`);";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use INNER JOIN.

```
DELETE a
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS a 
INNER JOIN YOUR_TABLE AS b ON a.UserName = b.UserName 
WHERE  a.UserID < b.UserID;
```

Or you can create another TEMP_TABLE, select distinct values from YOUR_TABLE to TEMP_TABLE, after it truncate YOUR_TABLE and copy TEMP_TABLE data to YOUR_TABLE and delete the TEMP_TABLE.

Answer (score 0):

This will delete duplicates. It'll keep the row with the lowest ID.

```
DELETE FROM bursary a
WHERE exists (select 1 from bursary b
               where a.UserName = b.UserName and
                     a.id > b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply unique key to your Username column will delete duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try below query:**

```
Delete bs from bursary bs,bursary bs2 
where bs.UserID > bs2.UserID and bs.UserName = bs2.UserName;
```

Using above query you can delete duplicate `username` entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from bursary b1 
where rowid > (SELECT min(rowid) FROM bursary b2 group by 
               b2.UserID,b2.UserName);
```

Answer (score -1):

please use add unique with ignore to delete all duplicate value

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `my_table`
    ADD UNIQUE (`Username`);
```

After that you can remove unique if you want.