# How do I delete duplicates from MariaDB where row_number <> 1

Tags: mariadb

I have my code here:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE EXISTS(
select *, row_number()
over (partition by LIST OF COLUMN NAMES
order by LIST OF COLUMN NAMES
) as row_number from TABLE_NAME
)
```

But it deletes all the records in the table. I only want to delete records in the table `WHERE row_number <> 1`.

I tried doing the following:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE EXISTS(
select *, row_number()
over (partition by LIST OF COLUMN NAMES
order by LIST OF COLUMN NAMES
) as row_number from TABLE_NAME WHERE row_number <> 1
)
```

and

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE row_number <> 1
WHERE EXISTS(
select *, row_number()
over (partition by LIST OF COLUMN NAMES
order by LIST OF COLUMN NAMES
) as row_number from TABLE_NAME 
)
```

but both gave errors saying check the mariadb syntax...can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete duplicate entries mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225912/delete-duplicate-entries-mysql)

Comment: consider which row you want delete when there is a duplicate.

Comment: i saw that link but i dont have 1 column to select.im not sure which single col to use...also i dont want to create temp tables. im trying to figure out if theres another way

Comment: i want to delete the rows where the row_number does not equal 1

Comment: If it doesn't matter which row you are deleting, pick a criteria that will be true like where `a.f1 < b.f1 or a.f2 < b.f2 or ....`. If there's a chance they are 100% identical, perhaps `ALTER IGNORE TABLE .. UNIQUE KEY` is the right way. After all, you want to be sure the table remains free of duplicates right